# JavaScript Regular Expression .replace usage

Tags: javascript, expression

I am trying to use a regular expression to just display 'Desired String' which is inside HTML code, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
alert("< TD>< B>< B>13COB251< /B> - Desired String< /B>< /TD>".replace(/(<[A-Z]*>)+13COB251(<\/[A-Z]*>)+ - ([a-z]*)(<\/[A-Z]*>)+/gi, "$3"))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you put your current code through Regexper you'll be given the following error:

> Expected one of *, +, ?, {, {,, (, [, ., \, $, |, ) at line 1, column 22 (byte 22) after /(<[A-Z]>)+13COB251(<

You need to [escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the `/` character by placing a backslash (`\` before it):

```
/(<[A-Z]>)+13COB251(<\/[A-Z]>)+ - ([a-z])(<\/[A-Z]>)+/gi
```

[image: Regex]

However as you can see, this isn't really accurate. One of [the best answers on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1317805) will explain why you shouldn't parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: The `\\` is there, but had been eaten by the wiki formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `/` characters in the pattern as that is the delimiter.

Then you need some more quantifiers. The pattern `(<[A-Z]>)+` matches one or more HTML tags, but only those that has a single character tag name. You need `(<[A-Z]+>)+` to match the `<TD>` tag also.

The pattern for the desired string also needs a quantifier, and the set needs to match more characters as the desired string doesn't contain only lower case characters.

```
alert("<TD><B><B>13COB251</B> - Desired String</B></TD>".replace(/(<[A-Z]+>)+13COB251(<\/[A-Z]>) - ([A-Za-z ]+)(<\/[A-Z]+>)+/gi, "$3"))
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RH6zc/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to account for the whitespace inside the tags and in your desired string.

```
/(< *[A-Z]*>)+13COB251(< *\/[A-Z]*>)+ - ([a-z ]*)(< *\/[A-Z]*>)+/gi
   ^                    ^                    ^     ^
```